# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at v.unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `window.onerror` that catches uncaught errors. Those errors then get reported to me via email.

I am getting error reports with the below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at v.unsubscribe (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:1:1), <anonymous>:49:241)
    at v.eval (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:1:1), <anonymous>:47:100)
    at v.publish (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:1:1), <anonymous>:48:456)
    at i (eval at <anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:1:1), <anonymous>:58:22)
```

I know what this error generally means, but I cannot find the cause of the error and searching around google / SO did not yield results. I cannot replicate the error because it's not happening to me, but it is happening to at least one user and seems to happen intermittently. My users use this application every weekday between normal work hours, and days will pass before this error gets reported to me again. It seems to happen to the same user, but I cannot be sure of this as my error reports are grouped up by UserAgent.

I have made sure that my scripts are loading in the correct order:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/errors.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Later, these other scripts are loaded:

```
<script src="assets/js/nimble.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/polyfill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know how I address this error or at least debug it even further?

Comment: "Shore up your logging" would be my only advice.  You need to pinpoint the precise line of code that's causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the error was so nebulous was because I was loading one entire page via AJAX, scripts included (I initially did this years ago before I knew better). I changed this and after a few days, I got a different error but with some of the same offending lines numbers.

```
/assets/js/jSignature.min.js:49:241
/assets/js/jSignature.min.js:47:111
/assets/js/jSignature.min.js:48:461
i@/assets/js/jSignature.min.js:58:29
```

I haven't addressed the error itself yet, but now I know what is causing the error.